# How can I pass a variable to be used as the condition in a filter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, filter

I am trying to filter an array of full names by a specific first name. I have created the `filterFirstName` function which accepts arguments for the name and the criteria to compare it to.

I then use that function in my filter. I looked up the syntax for filter `callback(element[, index[, array]]`. The element is the `fullName` but the `nameQuery` isn't the `index` or `array`.

I passed the `fullNames` array and `"John"` string as my arguments in case it knew to use `"John"` as the `nameQuery` variable. That also received an error.

I could not find any guidance showing this scenario so I may need to be directed to a different approach.

```
     //loop to get random names with one person named "John Smith"  
     var fullNames = (getNames = () => {
        let names = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
          names.push(`Human${i} Person${i}`);
        }
        names.push("John Smith");
        return names;
      })();

      var filterFirstName = (fullName, nameQuery) =>
        fullName.split(" ")[0] === nameQuery;

      var searchFirstNames = (namesAr, nameQuery) =>
        namesAr.filter(filterFirstName)(fullNames, "John");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify the two functions into one.

```
   //loop to get random names with one person named "John Smith"  
   var fullNames = (getNames = () => {
      let names = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        names.push(`Human${i} Person${i}`);
      }
      names.push("John Smith");
      return names;
    })();

    var searchFirstNames = (namesAr, nameQuery) => namesAr.filter(person => person.split(" ")[0] === nameQuery)

    searchFirstNames(fullNames, "John")
```

Comment: I had it as a one liner but separated it out since it wasn't using `"John"` as the `nameQuery` in the filter. The syntax didn't seem to support using a variable with the filter.

Comment: Can you try my answer? It should be working as you intended.

Comment: Sorry, I did and it produced an error. I just ran it again and it worked. I'm assuming it didn't save prior to running it the first time. Thank you!